# Shiny.setInputValue triggers twice

Tags: r, shiny

I will dynamically create checkboxes in a datatable, so my example now may seem a little silly:

I create a checkbox and clicking on it shall be communicated to R in some way. This is what I have tried, for some reason the event is triggered twice. Any thoughts on why this happens and what to do about it?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  HTML(
    "
    <label><input id='testcheckbox' type='checkbox' onclick='Shiny.setInputValue(id=\"num\", value=4)'/><span>Set numeric value to 4</span></label>
    "
  ),
  numericInput("num",value=-99, label="numeric value"),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$num,{
    print(input$num)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: You see that the numeric input is not updated, but has printed quite a lot]

Answer (score 0):

At the start `ObserveEvent()` read the input.

Try   `ignoreInit = TRUE`.

```
   observeEvent(input$num,{
     print(input$num)
   },ignoreInit = TRUE)
```

https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.7.4/observeevent